# How do I change default application for a file in Windows 10?

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

I'm using Windows 10 64 bit. When I open .py files using the command prompt it opens the file in pycharm. I would like to open the files in python. Is there an alternative command I can use to open the file with python? Or is there some setting i can alter to make python the default app when I open .py files using command prompt? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It's because you may have made PyCharm your default program to open `.py` files. You just need to change default app for file type. There's a option in windows for doing this :

Just search **"Choose default apps by file type"** in windows search bar. And choose python (or any suitable program) as default app for `.py` files.

Comment: This is more suited to be in a form of a comment. If you don't want, the kindly elaborate more on the answer